# On-prem 2019: "Default web service is null"

Tags: 2019

I have a demo/test on-premise environment where every IIS site including central admin is throwing this exception. It was working fine a couple of weeks ago, then when I started up the environment today, this is happening.

Searching for the message gives 0 hits on Google, and I have no idea what it means at all.

````
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Default web service is null
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.GetHostHeaderLookupKey(Uri uri, SPFarm farm)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteCache.LookupHostHeaderSite(Uri requestUri, SPFarm farm, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Lookup(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Boolean fallbackToHttpContext, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache, SPAlternateUrl& alternateUrl, ISPSiteLookupInfo& hostHeaderSiteInfo, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, String& siteRedirectUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, SPResourcePath& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken, Boolean readOnlyIntent)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)```
````

Comment: What is the value of `$farm = Get-SPFarm;$farm.Services.Count`?